# Are river rocks and stones a renewable resource?

Tags: rocks, resources

Imagine the polished / unpolished rocks and stones that people use to decorate their homes and gardens.

Are they a renewable resource? Are there plenty of them?

If we give 200 pounds of them to each human being alive, would we run out?

Comment: Yes, rocks are a renewable resource.  There is new igneous rock creation every day at volcanoes and sea-floor spreading locations.  As rocks go through the geologic cycle, they can eventually become "river rock" or even sand.  However, the rate of renewal is very slow (millions of years?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No**, I think you already know this but Rocks are not a renewable resource. Just because there are a 'lot' of rocks does not mean it is renewable [e.g There are lots of coal here], Rocks come in a limited amount here on Earth. [Are Rocks Renewable?](https://www.google.com/search?q=Are%20Rocks%20Renewable%3F&rlz=1CASFJY_enUS1020&oq=Are%20Rocks%20Renewable%3F&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i512l2j0i22i30l7.3769j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&safe=active&ssui=on)

Oh and Yes, It is possible to give 7 billion people 200 pounds of rock each considering the fact that 65 percent of the Earth is made up of Ingenious rocks and 66% is made of basalt, etc. Im 100% sure we can supply 7 Billion Humans with a [200 pound rock](https://www.google.com/search?q=200%20Pound%20Rock&rlz=1CASFJY_enUS1020&oq=200%20Pound%20Rock&aqs=chrome..69i57j0i22i30j0i390.2317j0j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&safe=active&ssui=on)

.

Comment: What about its availability? Do we have enough to give 7.5 billion people 200 lbs each?

Comment: @BigCatPublicSafetyAct I edited my answer.